# command run with root but not with sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, amazon-ec2, sudoers, supervisord

I am running `supervisorctl` command with `root` and `without root` user. 
With `root` user it is ok but with `sudo` it is not working. 
Here is the output:

```
[ec2-user@stg etc]$ sudo supervisorctl status
sudo: supervisorctl: command not found
```

Now I run with `root` user:

```
[ec2-user@stg etc]$ sudo su -
Last login: Tue Jun  6 03:02:55 UTC 2017 on pts/1
[root@stg ~]# supervisorctl status
kafka                            BACKOFF   Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
zookeeper                        RUNNING   pid 24697, uptime 0:25:11
```

`PATH` variable is shown below:

```
[root@stg ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin

[ec2-user@stg etc]$ echo $PATH
/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
```

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, and you've correctly identified the source. There are two possible solutions, making sure that all `PATH` entries present for `root`  are also present for `ec2-user` by adding the following to your bash profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin:$PATH"
```

Or, IMO the more elegant solution, make sure your `PATH` includes the specific directory containing `supervisorctl`.

You should start by finding the parent directory by running `whereis supervisorctl` under `root`.

```
# whereis supervisorctl
/whatever/path/bin
```

Which should then be included in your bash profile

```
$PATH="/whatever/path/bin:$PATH"
```